# Laravel 5.4 properly check if item is in array before returning result

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I am checking working on an invites only platform. You need to enter a valid token to get on board.

only the first token validates, any other token in the table is not even checked. What will be the best way to structure this to check all the tokens and only go to the else statement after checking the array.

```
    $this->validate($request,['pin' => 'required|numeric|digits:6']);

    $token = $request->input('pin');


    $all_pins  = \App\Pin::all()->toArray();
     if (in_array($token,$all_pins,true))
        {

            $user  = Auth::user()->id;
            $user = $this->user->find($user);
            $user->pin = $token;
            $user->is_activated = true;
            $user->has_pin = true;
            $user->save();

            flash('Your Pin was valid, Welcome', 'success');
            return redirect()->route('token_page');

        }

        else
        {
            flash('Sorry this pin is not valid', 'warning');
            return redirect()->route('reg_token_check');
        }`
```

`

Comment: show the output of $token and $all_pins

Comment: I dd that and they were valid. what am trying to say that it should check all, but in this case, when it checks one and its not valid, it returns the else statement

Comment: do you have one line space before else ?

Comment: you might not get it with that. becaues in_array will check once only. wait will give you one soultion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($all_pins as $value){
if($token == $value){
//do if part
    }
else{
//do else part
    }
}
```

try this